# Crash on Chrome when writing file on Webgl

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, filestream, unity-webgl

In Unity3d Webgl I download and write big file (about 100 mb and more) to cache (indexeddb).

I downloaded file with `UnityWebRequest` and write file in downloadHandler.
Sometimes after call `filestream.Write()` or `filestream.Flush()` Chrome will crash.

Exception not available, only crash tab of chrome.
Crash happens abount in 50 percent of dowloads.

```
public class Downloader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IEnumerator DownloadFileCoroutine(string url, string filePath,     string clientName, int fileId, Action<int> downloadedCallback)
    {
    var currentWebRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    currentWebRequest.downloadHandler = new ToFileDownloadHandler(new byte[64 * 1024], filePath);

    var downloadHendler = (currentWebRequest.downloadHandler as ToFileDownloadHandler);
    currentWebRequest.Send();
    while (!currentWebRequest.isDone && !currentWebRequest.isNetworkError && !currentWebRequest.isHttpError)
    { 
        if (currentWebRequest.isNetworkError)
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }

    if (currentWebRequest.isNetworkError)
    {
        downloadHendler.Cancel();
    }
    else
    {
        /// suceess
    }
}

public class ToFileDownloadHandler : DownloadHandlerScript
{
    private int _expected = -1;
    private long _received = 0;
    private readonly string _filepath;
    private readonly FileStream _fileStream = null;
    private bool _canceled = false;

    public ToFileDownloadHandler(byte[] buffer, string filepath) : base(buffer)
    {
        CreateDir();
        _filepath = filepath;
        _fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    }

    protected override byte[] GetData() { return null; }

    protected override bool ReceiveData(byte[] data, int dataLength)
    {
        if (data == null || data.Length < 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        _received += dataLength;
        if (!_canceled)
        {
            _fileStream.Write(data, 0, dataLength);
            _fileStream.Flush();
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected override float GetProgress()
    {
        if (_expected < 0) return 0;
        return (float)_received / _expected;
    }

    protected override void CompleteContent()
    {
        _fileStream.Close();
        _isComplete = true;
    }

    protected override void ReceiveContentLength(int contentLength)
    {
        _expected = contentLength;
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        if (_canceled) return;
        _canceled = true;
        if (_fileStream != null)
        {
            _fileStream.Close();
        }
        File.Delete(_filepath);
    }

        private void CreateDir()
    {
        cachePath = Application.persistentDataPath;
        if (!Directory.Exists(cachePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(cachePath);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning your Unity version. Also, why not try it on Firefox and also on a standard build and tell me if this problem is happen there too

Comment: Unity version is 2017.1.p03.
I develop for chrome browser and webgl.

Comment: Try this on Firefox and see if that issue is still there. I just want to know if this is Chrome specific issue

Comment: In FireFox always get error: "out of memory" when write file with FileStream

Comment: At least we see an actual error now. Maybe this is WebGL bug on Unity. Try build for PC and Android and see what happens too.

Comment: Its okey standalone.

Comment: Open the file with `FileMode.Append` instead of `FileMode.Create` and tell me what happens. Also, why not just store those downloaded bytes to an array, when download is done (`CompleteContent`) , save them instead of saving each time `ReceiveData` is called....This may actually fix your issue

Comment: I open file with File.Append. It`s also crush. Sometimes crash became before write file after call ReceiveContentLength(int contentLength) (DownloadHandlerScript)

Comment: In webgl CompleteContent not called while not whole file dowloaded.

Comment: `CompleteContent` should be called when the data has finished downloading. If this is not the case then file for a bug report on both issue

Comment: I try download all bytes to an array and then its write to file, but got error when read its data